# Sort comma separated numbers in a single String Array In Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have one String array:

```
String[] digits = {"2,5,1,6"};
```

I want to sort this string array, without using a temp variable in Java.

Like this 1,2,5,6

Comment: Which language you are using?

Comment: am using java language

Comment: Just a note, since you are using array, instead of declaring it as `{"2,5,1,6"}`, try this `{"2", "5", "1", "6"}`

Comment: Do you want to sort the Strings in the array (currently there is only one) or would you like to change the string inside the array to "1,2,5,6"?

Comment: @Arvind  : I know if i declare {"2", "5", "1", "6"} like this , sorting is possible by Using Arrays.sort(digits);

Comment: @dosw : i would like to change the string inside the array to "1,2,5,6"

Comment: How should `"3,2,11,4"` be sorted?

Comment: @Pshemo  : You can sort by like this .     String []target=digits.split(",");
               Arrays.sort(target);

Comment: @Priya I know, but I am wondering if results will be same as expected by you since `target` will be now sorted like `[11, 2, 3, 4]` (alphabetical order) not `[2, 3, 4, 11]` (numerical order).

Comment: @Pshemo :  oh k :-) got it .. mistake..

Comment: You still didn't answer my question. What should be expected result? `[11, 2, 3, 4]` or `[2, 3, 4, 11]`? Are you interested in alphabetical order or numerical order?

Comment: @Pshemo :  [2, 3, 4, 11].... Numerical order..

Answer (score 3):

```
String [] digits = string.split(",");
Arrays.sort( digits );
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 8 you can write something like

```
String[] digits = { "2,11,5,1,6" };
digits[0] = Stream.of(digits[0].split(","))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)//convert value to int
        .sorted()//sort integer values
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)//convert values back to String
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));//join values using "," delimiter

System.out.println(digits[0]);
```

Output: `1,2,5,6,11`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(string.split(",")));
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: I don't think this works ... OPs String has no whitespaces :P.

Comment: @Tom:- Then remove the whitespace ;)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to convert the items inside the digits array into integers

```
int [] forSorting = new int [digits.lenght];

for(int x = 0; x < digits.length; x++){

 forSorting [x] = Integer.parseInt(digits [x]);

}

//sort forSorting here
```